# Polymorphic types : How to ?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, caml

I'm reading this [wiki](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/FAQ/definitions_de_types-eng.html) about types in Caml , and I must admit I'm struggling to understand how polymorphic types are dealt with syntactically , so in general how can one define a polymorphic type ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymorphism shows up in OCaml in many places. The polymorphic types discussed on that wiki are simply parameterized types. In some sense, they are type-level functions. To define a one-parameter type:

```
type 'a <name> = <definition using 'a>
```

For example

```
type 'a tagged = { value: 'a; tag: int }
```

In the `<definition>` part you use the type name (`'a`) as a formal parameter standing for whatever concrete type is supplied later.

After declaring the type (which declares `value` and `tag` as record fields), you can make values of the type:

```
# { value = "abc"; tag = 4 };;
- : string tagged = {value = "abc"; tag = 4}
```

The compiler infers that the type of this value is `string tagged` because the `value` field has type `string`.

Multiple parameter types are defined using parentheses to enclose the type parameters:

```
type ('a, 'b) name = <definition using 'a and 'b>
```

For example:

```
type ('a, 'b) paired = { first: 'a; second: 'b }
```

This defines the field names `first` and `second`, which you can then use to make values:

```
# { first = 1.5; second = [3] };;
- : (float, int list) paired = {first = 1.5; second = [3]}
```

To summarize, the syntax for making polymorphic (parameterized) types is the same as the syntax for making types, extended with the use of symbols like `'a` for the type parameters.